# .Net - Azure AD Authentication for Intranet Web Application

Tags: .net, azure, authentication, active-directory

We are developing Intranet web application using NET framework is 4.6.1 (C#). Both UI (MVC) and backend (Web API) would be deployed as separate web apps in IIS. The requirement is to authenticate user against Azure AD hosted on Cloud. We are able to achieve the same by referring mostly to the below article. As soon as user access the Web App, user is redirected to Azure login page and redirected to web app home page after successful authentication.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-headless

Now Client has asked us not to show/redirect the user to any login page. As user is already connected to client network, login should happen automatically and user should not get any login page. Please share any pointers for achieving this.

Comment: Do you have on-prem AD and are syncing to AAD?

Comment: Yes. Users from On-Prem AD are getting synced with Azure AD every hour.

Comment: Then you can setup e.g. pass through authentication to allow instantenous login when within the intranet.

Comment: Here is the documentation for PTA: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-pta

Comment: Thanks. Will try this approach.